# Solve integral $\int\frac{1}{(x^2-1)\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

$$\int\frac{1}{(x^2-1)\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$$
I'm trying to solve this integral. First I substituted : $x=\tan(t)$; $t=\arctan(x)$

Then $$ dx=\frac{1}{\cos^2(t)}\,dt$$

Now by simplifying I'm to this step $$ \int\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin^2(t)-\cos^2(t)}\,dt$$

What can i do now ..

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: $u=\sin(t)\implies du=\cos(t)\,dt$

Comment: How do you get from $\int \frac{\cos x }{\sin^2x - \cos^2x} dx$ to a difference of two integrals??  }

Comment: You aren't allowed to simplify fractions like that...

Comment: Sorry about my mistake ,i just edited question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\int\frac{\cos t}{\sin^2 t-\cos^2 t}dt$$

Use $\cos^2 t = 1-\sin^2 t$ to modify the denominator
$$\int\frac{\cos t}{2\sin^2 t-1}dt$$
Substitute $u=\sin t$, $du =\cos t \, dt$
$$\int\frac{1}{2u^2-1}du$$
Now integrate using partial fractions or otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

**Other approach**

Put $ x=\sinh(t) $ with

$$dx=\cosh(t)dt$$

$$\sqrt{x^2+1}=\sqrt{\sinh^2(t)+1}=\cosh(t)$$

$$x^2-1=(\sinh^2(t)-1)$$

It becomes
$$\int \frac{dt}{(\sinh(t)+1)(\sinh(t)-1)}$$

$$=\frac 12\int (\frac{1}{\sinh(t)-1}-\frac{1}{\sinh(t)+1})dt$$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute  $t= \frac{\sqrt2 x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

\begin{align}
I=& \int\frac{1}{(x^2-1)\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx\\
= &\frac1{\sqrt2} \int \frac{1}{t^2-1} dt=\frac1{2\sqrt2} \ln|\frac{t-1}{t+1}|
= \frac1{2\sqrt2} \ln|\frac{\sqrt2 x-\sqrt{x^2+1}}{\sqrt2 x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}|
\end{align}
Alternatively
$I=-\frac1{2\sqrt2}\coth^{-1}\frac{3x+\frac1x}{2\sqrt2 \sqrt{x^2+1}}
$